# Question on definition of inverse number theoretic transformation

Tags: nt.number-theory, cryptography

In the paper [Porkodi and Arumuganathan - Public key cryptosystem based on number theoretic transforms](https://publications.waset.org/15309/pdf) I found the following statement on the second page regarding the Inverse Number Theoretic Transformation (INTT), there the INTT is defined as follows:

$$h_l = N^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} H_k g^{-lk} \pmod{m},\; l=0,\ldots,N-1$$
where $m$ is a composite number and
$$NN^{-1} = 1 \pmod{m},\quad g^N = 1 \pmod{m}$$
and
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} g^{uk} = 0 \pmod{m}. $$
Equivalently,
$$ \gcd(g^u - 1, m) = 1 $$
for every $u$ such that $N/u$ is a prime.

---

I am now interested in:

1. To know what exactly the condition $\gcd(g^u - 1, m) = 1$ says. For this I have a guess: Assuming $g$ is a primitive root modulo $m$ with order $N$, then $\gcd(g^u - 1, m) = 1$ ensures that $g^u \not\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, can we say so?
2. How to get the idea that $N/u$ is a prime number and why that is important in this context. I am just interested in how one comes up with this last condition ($\gcd(g^u - 1, m) = 1$
   for every $u$ such that $N/u$ is a prime) in the definition.

I look forward to helpful comments.

Comment: The NTT is an instance of the FFT trick in the ring $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$. See [Bernstein, section 7](https://cr.yp.to/papers/m3-20010811-retypeset-20220327.pdf) for pointers.